# Can I get title of wordpress page in to subject line of e-mail using maito function

Tags: mailto

I have a link on a wordpress site

```
<a href="mailto:enquiries@britishartportfolio.co.uk?subject=**WORDPRESS PAGE TITLE**">Enquiry about painting</a></p>
```

Is it possible to get the subject of the e-amil to be populated by the title of the wordpress page/post?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that:

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com?subject=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">LINK TEXT</a>
```